# how should I apply libsndfile library in vscode?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, header-files, libsndfile

I needed to use libsndfile library in C, and I am using MinGW compiler in VScode.
I have set up the library by copying header files and .lib file in the project's `sndfile` directory.
Then to use the library in my code, I edited my `c_cpp_properties.json` and `tasks.json` like the picture, linking its directory and defining its paths.
But while linking it, the Warning

`"property linker is not allowed"`

popped up.

And when I compiled the code including the library, The error

`C:\Users\user\Fourier\noteanalyzer.c:6:20: fatal error: sndfile.h: No such file or directory #include<sndfile.h>`
appeared.

Project directory is

`C:\Users\user\Fourier`
(since I was studying fft and sound processing with this)

Where library header is located is

`C:\Users\user\Fourier\sndfile\include\sndfile.h`

`error`-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb00y.png)

`c_cpp_properties`-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/14PEl.png)

`tasks`-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vU23.png)

I have tried removing the linker and only set the path of the library, and it seemed to have no error or red markers, but after I compile It resulted in same error.

I have tried removing all the other files except header files and `.lib` file, it doesn't seem to resolve the path error.

I have added the system environment variable of the library, no effect.

I wonder if the error"property linker not allowed" causes the problem, but there was not much information on that error I could find.

Comment: Is your project using CMake? Also, are you familiar with the basic idea of linking libraries in C?

Comment: No, It's not and I am new to C libraries. This is my first time implementing library in C.

Comment: I never use Visual Studio for C (or C++), I find it overcomplicates things, so I will try my best to help. You may be aware that you need to do 2 things, that is getting your include file as well as actually linking the library. The error about your header not being found I think is because in your properties file under the "includePath" all the way at the top you have ${workspacefolder}/sndfile, try making this ${workspacefolder}/sndfile/include. I also think you manually have to add the -l (lib name) and -L (lib path) flags for under compilerArgs.